# GCP Terraform: Setting port for backend service

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

Reading through the docs here:

https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/compute_backend_service.html

We can define backend service:

```
resource "google_compute_backend_service" "kubernetes-nginx-prod" {
  name                            = "kubernetes-nginx-prod"
  health_checks                   = [google_compute_health_check.kubernetes-nginx-prod-healthcheck.self_link]

  backend {
    group = replace(google_container_node_pool.pool-1.instance_group_urls[0], "instanceGroupManagers", "instanceGroups")
    # TODO missing port 31443
  }
}
```

It seems we are unable to set backend service port via the Terraform settings:

[image]

Recreating the backend service without this settings actually leads to downtime for us and the port must be written manually.

Answer (score 5):

We need to reference the port name that we gave in the instance group for e.g.

```
resource "google_compute_backend_service" "test" {
  name          = "test-service"
  port_name     = "test-port"
  protocol      = "HTTP"
  timeout_sec   = 5
  health_checks = []

  backend {
    group = "${google_compute_instance_group.test-ig.self_link}"
  }
}

resource "google_compute_instance_group" "test-ig" {
  name        = "test-ig"
  instances = []

  named_port {
    name = "test-port"
    port = "${var.app_port}"
  }

  zone = "${var.zone}"
}
```

Comment: thanks! however - the instance groups are created automatically via Kubernetes (`google_container_cluster`) - do I want to keep these manually in the terraform state?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by using a terraform data source to extract the instance group data from my `google_container_node_pool`, and then appending a `google_compute_instance_group_named_port` resource to it.

NOTE my google_container_node_pool spans 3 zones (a,b,c) and the below code highlights the solution for only zone c

```
# extract google_compute_instance_group from google_container_node_pool
data "google_compute_instance_group" "instance_group_zone_c" {
  # .2 refers to the last of the 3 instance groups in my node pool (zone c)
  name    = regex("([^/]+)/?$", "${google_container_node_pool.k8s_node_pool.instance_group_urls.2}").0
  zone    = regex("${var.region}-?[abc]", "${google_container_node_pool.k8s_node_pool.instance_group_urls.2}")
  project = var.project_id
}

# define a named port to attach to the google_compute_instance group in my node  pool
resource "google_compute_instance_group_named_port" "named_port_zone_c" {
  group = data.google_compute_instance_group.instance_group_zone_c.id
  zone = data.google_compute_instance_group.instance_group_zone_c.zone
  name = "port31090"
  port = 31090
}
```